# VOIP push notifications in android

Tags: android, ios, voip, callkit, pushkit

I am developing a VOIP app. VOIP push is sent from amazon SNS, using push kit and call kit we show caller screen. This caller screen can be presented even when app is in background or quit.

Unfortunately android does not have VOIP push. How it can be implemented in android? or is there any solution that would work in both platforms?

Comment: I am also stack here. i know this can be accomplished with ios. question is how does whatsapp android handle it? if am not using websockets how do i go about it without polling server @Hasya

Answer (score 3):

In iOS you can not keep 2 process in running from 1 app even not in foreground, background or terminated state.So pushkit technique introduced to notify user about incoming VOIP call in terminated state.

In Android you can keep 2 process running together, if you close ( terminate ) your app then still 1 another process can be live in background and terminated state.

You can implement websocket, and websocket has to be another service apart from your Android app. Websocket service will be keep running even in terminated state, once you receive some response on websocket you can invoke your main app about incoming call.

Like Skype, WhatsApp other app does not keep sending request and handle response to know user is online or offline. That works on websocket technique. Any single change on server, server will send information to websocket.

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't have the idea of "VoIP Push" equivalent to iOS. Warnings will simply work, including information just messages where you can begin an Activity as opposed to demonstrating a push.

In the event that you have to call custom class for indicating local UI for instance, you would utilize the Android NotificationExtenderService so you can abrogate the warning and show your custom UI or start your custom Activity.